# How can I prove the experiment data follows heavy-tail distribution?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, distribution, delay, probability

I have several test results of server response delay. According to our theory analysis, the delay distribution should have heavy-tail behavior. But how could I prove that the test result does follow heavy-tail distribution?

Comment: I have no idea what this is asking, but I expect you'll get a better response from [the statistics stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks for your suggestions, I will post the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert, but I think that estimating the [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) of your delay distribution would be a good start.

If you know the theoretical delay distribution, you can also do a [goodness of fit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straightforward way is to make a best fit of half normal distribution to and look how well it describe the tail.
In Python you can make this with the help of `scipy.stats.halfnorm.fit()` or use a **longtail** module that is dedicated for plotting and analysing heavy tails (https://github.com/Mottl/longtail):

```
import numpy as np
import longtail

# generate random values from heavy tailed distribution (let's take Laplace)
X = np.random.laplace(size=10000)
X = X[X>0]  # take only right half of the distribution

# get best fit of half normal distribution to our data:
params = longtail.fit_distributions(X, distributions=['halfnorm'])

# visualize X and best fit:
longtail.plot(X, params=params)
```

Since points at the tail are above the half normal approximation, the given distribution can be considered as having heavier tail than half normal:

[image]
[image]